# JSON Object to Spinner crash app

Tags: java, json, xml

I have the following problem.
A date picker where i select a date, this gets put into an array with the username.The array used to get the users start times by using the GetMemberPatrolStartTimes in Parser.This returns the JSON object that is then sent to the patrol history which populates a spinner.

I can see that the spinner gets populated but as soon as i click to drop the spinner down i get the error that is attached in the file.

Now i can read the error, but using it to solve the problem i can not get right.

Appreciate all help, guidance and any constructive criticism

Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

This is being caught in a UncaughtException method
**eyeWatchApi.java**

```
public JSONObject GetMemberPatrolStartTimes(ArrayList<String> details)throws Exception {
    JSONObject result = null;
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
    o.put("interface","eyeWatchApi");
    o.put("method", "GetMemberPatrolStartTimes");
    p.put("details",mapObject(details));
    o.put("parameters", p);
    String s = o.toString();
    String r = load(s);
    result = new JSONObject(r);
    return result;
}
```

**Parser.java**

```
public Object GetPatrolHistoryStartTimes(JSONObject object){
    String[] id_Array;
    String[] time_Array;

    try{
        JSONArray a = object.getJSONArray("Value");

        id_Array = new String[a.length()];
        time_Array = new String[a.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject b = a.getJSONObject(i);

            id_Array[i]=b.getString("startID");
            time_Array[i]=b.getString("startTime");
            return new Object[]{id_Array,time_Array};
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
      return e;
    }catch (Exception e){
        return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Patrol_History.java**

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patrol_history,container,false);

        timeSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.TimeSpinner);

        timeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.load_polly_btn :
        {
            drawpoliline();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.select_date_txt :
        {
            Date_Pick_Dialog picker = new Date_Pick_Dialog();
            picker.setDatePickerDialogFragmentEvents(this);
            picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDateSelected(String _date) {

        patrolHistoryManager = new PatrolHistoryManager(getActivity());
        patrolHistoryManager.setDate(_date);
        selectDate_tv.setText(_date);
        date = _date;
       new AsyncSendDetails().execute(date);


    //new AsyncGetAvailibleSlots().execute(_date);
}

public class AsyncSendDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object[]> {

    @Override
    protected Object[] doInBackground(String... params) {


        eyeWatchApi api = new eyeWatchApi();
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        detailsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        detailsList.add(userName);
        detailsList.add(params[0]);

        Object[] ob = new Object[0];
        try {
            ob = (Object[]) parser.GetPatrolHistoryStartTimes(api.GetMemberPatrolStartTimes(detailsList));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ob;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object[] ob) {
        if(ob != null)
        {
        timeID = (String[]) ob[0];
        times = (String[]) ob[1];


            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.countries_spinner_item, times);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.countries_spinner_item_droplist);
            timeSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Slots Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

**Layout File**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint="Select Date"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#d32f2f"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/select_date_txt"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:text="02/05/2016"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/select_date_txt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/TimeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#d32f2f"
        android:layout_below="@+id/select_date_txt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    </Spinner>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TimeSpinner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_weight="0.73"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



</fragment>
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Load Lines"
    android:id="@+id/load_polly_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What error? Whats the logcat output? You said you get an error?

Comment: sorry trying to edit to add it

Comment: i have added it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

After almost a week of struggling i have just found the answer so i will be keeping it on here for all to see if there is a need for it

```
**Parser.java**

public Object GetPatrolHistoryStartTimes(JSONObject object){
String[] id_Array;
String[] time_Array;

try{
    JSONArray a = object.getJSONArray("Value");

    id_Array = new String[a.length()];
    time_Array = new String[a.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject b = a.getJSONObject(i);

        id_Array[i]=b.getString("startID");
        time_Array[i]=b.getString("startTime");
       }
return new Object[]{id_Array,time_Array};
}catch (JSONException e){
  return e;
}catch (Exception e){
    return e;
}
return null;
}
```

The problem was that my return of the object should not have been inside the for statement but rather after it, after the loop has been completed